# "Whether or not..." vs. "whether... or not"

Tags: word-order, conjunctions, conditionals, negation

I'm confused with the placement of 'or not' with 'whether' in a sentence. E.g.

> 1. - I'm not sure whether I should go or not.
>    - I'm not sure whether or not I should go.
> 2. - Whether you stay or not, you will be charged.
>    - Whether or not you stay, you will be charged.

Can someone please advise which one is correct? If both are correct, is there certain situation where to use one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter.  Both ways are correct.

Consider the following two examples [Pearson Longman](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00095.htm) cites from *The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage*:

- I’ll call you tomorrow whether or not I have the answer for you then.
- I’ll call you tomorrow whether I have the answer for you then or not.

If you go to that link and read a little more there, you will also see that in your first sentence, you can even omit the "or not," for example:

- I'm not sure whether I should go.

You can't do that in the second example because "whether" is being used adverbially to modify "charged."